# React native Windows: Emit keypresses to system

Tags: react-native, keyboard-events

I am currently evaluating the possibility to emit keypresses (like left / right arrow or page up / page down) programmatically to the system with React Native in Windows or macOS.

The use case would be a remote clicker for Powerpoint presentations.

All I find online is the possibility to send keypress events to the RN app, not the system.

Is that something that is possible at all or would I need to build this in e.g. Java?

Thanks for your ideas in advance!